# How to structure my Ionic App directory when deploying through Cloud Run?

Tags: google-cloud-run

Specifically, should the ionic app live inside of the Cloud Run directory created by Cloud Code. Or should it be a completely different directory and have the Dockerfile point to that app directory? What is the easiest and cleanest approach?

Answer (score 0):

It is best practice to keep the Iconic app in a separate directory from the Cloud Run directory created by cloud code. Because it is easier to manage and update the code separately.

Alternatively, you can create a docker file in the app directory to deploy the iconic app in the cloud run.

For automation, you can use CI/CD pipeline to build and deploy the process.